# How can I dynamically load related data in a second table whenever the user clicks on a row from the first table (MVC 5)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have two tables, Students and Classes, and they are linked through a third table called StudentClasses.

*Students*

```
id          Name      Age    
----------------------------
1     |     John  |   31
2     |     Bob   |   22 
3     |     Alice |   18
```

*Classes*

```
id          ClassName   
----------------------------
1     |       Geography  
2     |       Math    
3     |       Science
4     |       Anthropology
5     |       Spanish
6     |       Literature
```

*StudentsClasses*

```
sid | cid
----------
1   |  1
1   |  3
1   |  4
2   |  2
2   |  4
3   |  6
```

In my view, I know I can access classes a student is taking using the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<Students>
...
...
...
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
      <tr>
         <td>item.Name</td>
         <td>item.Age</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         @foreach (var item2 in item.StudentClasses)
         {
            <td>item2.ClassName</td>
         }
      </tr>
}
</table>
...
...
...
```

Using the current way, (if I'm getting my terminology correct) the classes each student takes are lazy-loaded in a nested for loop. I.e.

```
Table1
-----------------------------------
|John 31                        |
|Geography Science Anthropology |
|Bob 22                         |
|Math Anthropology              |
|Alice 18                       |
|Literature                     |
------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is have a completely separate table, so that when a user clicks on a student name, it would populate the table with their classes dynamically. As opposed to all the classes each student is taking being listed beneath their student. For example, if the user clicks on John, they would see the following:

```
Table 1                           Table 2
---------             --------------------------------
|John 31 |            |Geography Science Anthropology |
|Bob 22  |            |                               |
|Alice 18|            |                               |
---------             ---------------------------------
```

And if they clicked on Bob, they would see:

```
Table 1                           Table 2
---------             --------------------------------
|John 31 |            |Math Anthropology              |
|Bob 22  |            |                               |
|Alice 18|            |                               |
---------             ---------------------------------
```

I realize that I can use ajax to dynamically update the table. However, I feel like this is a waste...after all, all the necessary data is already sent to the view. Why do I have go back to the server with a student ID, search for all classes associated with the student ID, and then pass it back to my view - when all that information is lazy-loaded?

Is there a simple way for me to dynamically load the classes for each student in a second table, updating the table with the related classes whenever the student name is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Razor it is important to note that while cshtml files result in HTML files on the client, they are templates that are processed by the server during a request to load the view.

statements like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

within the cshtml are processed server-side to ultimately generate HTML that contains the data provided by your Model. Right now your Model would be either eager loading, or relying on lazy loading to get the courses for a student. If you remove the:

```
     @foreach (var item2 in item.StudentClasses)
     {
        <td>item2.ClassName</td>
     }
```

then the resulting HTML would just list the students without their classes, but then how would we get the classes at the client?

The simplest answer is Posting a Form when the user selects a student. The Razor page can accept a `studentId` parameter which loads a resulting table for classes if/where a Student is selected. This results in a post-back to the server every time you select a student, but results in a very simple Razor page which will refresh generally quite quickly. It also reduces the overall payload of "data" being sent to the client, but it does result in extra traffic to the server where pretty much any action taken on a page could result in a post-back. Many developers "poo-poo" this approach as for larger systems it has scale limits, but it works perfectly fine for simple scenarios.

Another option to avoid post-backs is to ensure the classes are loaded, then give the client page has a JSON copy of the data. A common way to do is via a `<script>` block that "captures" the model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

</script>
```

What this ends up doing is when the page is composed, the entire model will be serialized to JSON, and accessible client side. There are a few drawbacks/considerations with this approach:

1. Data size. You are now sending your entire collection of data to the client, on top of the generate HTML for the students, you are sending all students and their respective classes.
2. You are exposing everything about your model to the client. By sending entities, the entire entity graph will be serialized and sent. This includes fields and related entities you don't intend to display.

In both cases it is generally better to project your entities to view models to ensure that the payload sent to the client is as small as possible, and reveals only what is needed.

From here then the implementation would be to wire up a Javascript event to each student item to then pull the associated Classes from the serialised "model" instance accessible from Javascript, build a resulting Table for the classes, then inject that generated HTML into a placeholder `<div>` set up. This adds a fair bit of code and complexity to your page, but avoids the post-back refresh. This does add complexity though to handle if/when a page does refresh as it is up to the client to track the selected Student.

A third option is sort of a mix of the two, using an Ajax call. The key here would be that when populating your Students at first, you minimize the data load to *just* the student details, not courses. Then when you click on a student, the Javascript makes an Ajax call to the server to retrieve either the raw JSON data for the courses and composes the view for the courses client-side, or it receives a serialized partial view (HTML) from the server in the response. A POST call can return a PartialView Response, however with Ajax calls it is generally better to return a JSON result so that you can provide something like a success/failure/error message along with the serialized view. In the success scenario that partial view is fed directly into a waiting placeholder `<div>`. This can make the solution a bit more complex, but the benefit is that you can still leverage Razor server-side to generate your partial views (course list) rather than building it with Javascript. Thought JS is perfectly fine for simple views. Like the second approach this also needs logic implemented to track the selected student so if a page is refreshed the server can send/render the selected courses. Rather than relying on URL parameters like the Form Postback, the Ajax calls can update session state server side so that a page post (form refresh etc) can still query the session state to determine if a student was selected and render a resulting course list.

Building responsive, scale-able web applications is a fairly involved topic with lots of different approaches and considerations. Ultimately start simple based on what you know you need, then target your searches for requirements or addressing issues as you face them. A lot of discussions around best practices and such (like using client-side frameworks etc.) stem from requirements faced by huge systems with a lot of functionality and millions of concurrent users. Starting off as a developer you'd be diving in way over your head worrying about those concerns. :) Take all advice (including mine) with a grain of salt and alway keep YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It) at the forefront of your investigations.

A good starting point if you are interested in the Ajax approach /w partial views:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/216439/Data-Validation-Using-Annotations-for-jQuery-Ajax

Comment: Wow! What an outstanding answer; thank you so much for taking the time to give me such thorough explanations! This more than gives me what I need to resolve my issue. My only complaint is that I can only upvote your answer one time! I think I will end up using your second approach, as ultimately the user will need all the information that is within the model. Thanks again!